# android listview with multiple xml files

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

I want to create a listview with multiple views in it like in google now for example.
Here is my ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Activity context;
private final List<String> city;
private final List<Integer> image;
private final List<String> temp;
private final List<String> humidity;
private final List<String> windspeed;
private final List<String> condition;


public CustomList(Activity context,
                  List<String> city,
                  List<Integer> image,
                  List<String> temp,
                  List<String>humidity,
                  List<String>windspeed,
                  List<String>condition) {
    super(context, R.layout.weather_item, city);
    this.context = context;
    this.city = city;
    this.temp = temp;
    this.humidity = humidity;
    this.image = image;
    this.windspeed = windspeed;
    this.condition = condition;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_item, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    TextView txtTemp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.info_one);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
    TextView txthumidity = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.humidity);
    TextView txtWind = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.wind_speed);
    TextView txtCond = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.info_two);
    txtCond.setText(condition.get(position));
    txtWind.setText(windspeed.get(position));
    txthumidity.setText(humidity.get(position));
    txtTitle.setText(city.get(position));
    txtTemp.setText(String.valueOf(temp.get(position))+"°");
    imageView.setImageResource(image.get(position));
    return rowView;
}
```

}

It currently inflates one xml file called "weather_item" located in layout folder.
I want to create a listview with two of those xml files so it will show the weather_item and my other layout so it will look something like this
[image: example of listview with several xml views in it]

Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible, you need to google it. There are lots of tutorials about it. You can use it as a starting point: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Comment: Is there a simpler tutorial that focuses more on the listview adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just override two methods in your custom adapter class and modify your getview to handle both types of layouts.

```
private static final int DATA_TYPE_WEATHER = 0;
private static final int DATA_TYPE_OTHER = 1;   
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // Return the total number of xml layouts you'll be using
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // You have the list position, look up the data in your array and
        // return the proper number for the data type
        if (/* test for weather data type */) {
            return DATA_TYPE_WEATHER;
        } else {
            return DATA_TYPE_OTHER;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // always check and re-use the convertView if it's not null!
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            if (/* test for weather data type */) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_item, null);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout, null);
            }
        }
        if (/* test for weather data type */) {
            // TODO setup the fields for weather layout
        } else {
            // TODO setup the fields for other layout
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer
I didn't quit understood what am i supposed to put in the "test for weather data type"

Comment: I didn't quite understood what am i supposed to put in the "test for weather data type" though

Comment: Well you're passing some array of objects to your arrayadapter. You should be able to look up the item in that array using `position` as the index and see if it corresponds with weather data or "other" data.

Comment: Ok just one more thing, i'm currently calling it like that
  final CustomList adapter = new
                    CustomList(listview_test.this, web, imageId,temp,humidity,WindSpeed,Condition);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

How should i do it now when i have two layouts?

Comment: You should define a weather class for with fields for all those values instead of a list for each field. Then you'll define another class for the "other" data. Last, define an interface that both will implement so that you can keep both types in the same array. Your constructor can then be rewritten to take a single array.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your all layouts into a vertical LinearLayout.